I can´t see UDP packets in a NFQUEUE queue on Ubuntu, even though the iptables rules are configured correctly
I am trying to capture UDP packets on an Ubuntu server using iptables and the NFQUEUE queue and then process them with an application. However, although I have configured the iptables rules correctly and the UDP packets appear to arrive at the server (as shown by tcpdump), I do not see them in the NFQUEUE queue.
This packets are created in another Computer (Sender) by a python Script and its connected directly to the Ubuntu Computer (Receiver) with a wired connection. I have checked that the packets are correct (recalculated Cheksums and proper structure).
Configuration and Operating system:
Ubuntu 24.04.
Kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic.
Rules im creating in the Ubuntu:

sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i enp0s31f6 -p udp --dport 12345 -j LOG --log-prefix "UDP packet detected: "
sudo iptables -I INPUT 2 -i enp0s31f6 -p udp --dport 12345 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

With tcpdump I have confirmed that UDP packets on port 12345 are reaching the server.

sudo tcpdump -i enp0s31f6 udp port 12345

tcpdump: listening on enp0s31f6, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
13:30:42.736329 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 2001, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 40)
    10.22.18.54.12345 > 192.168.1.10.12345: UDP, length 12

If instead of using the enp0s31f6 interface I use loopback(lo)  together with the command:

echo 'hello world' | nc -u localhost 12345

It does work correctly.
To check that it works I am seeing how many packets have passed the created rule. In the loopback case we have 1 packet indicating that it has worked, and each time I run the above command I see it increase by 1.
While the enp0s31f6 rule does not increase by anything and the dmesg log shows absolutely nothing.

sudo iptables -L -v -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 39989 packets, 129M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 NFQUEUE    17   --  enp0s31f6 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:12345 NFQUEUE num 0
    1     40 NFQUEUE    17   --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:12345 NFQUEUE num 0

What could be happening and what am I doing wrong? What do I have to change to start capturing UDP packets on the enp0s31f6 interface?
